# Accessing MQ with JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq

i am using MQ7 and trying to access a queue with JMS api's. Getting this error.
Has anyone seen it before? How do i resolve this? TIA

> Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: 
>   JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI. The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.  See the linked exception for further information.
>
> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd in java.library.path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost always caused by a combination of an incomplete client install and/or a CLASSPATH issue.  Many people grab the jar files rather than performing the complete install and do not necessarily get all of them.  In addition to insuring all required binaries are present, using the install media provides several additional capabilities such as diagnostics and trace.  It also assures that maintenance can be applied.  The WMQ client install media are available for free download as [SupportPac MQC7](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQC7).  The CLASSPATH setting should be as described in the [WebSphere MQ Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10330_.htm) manual.

If the client install is performed from the IBM media and the environment is set up as per the docs, this fixes nearly all cases such as you have reported here.  There are a few Install Verification Test apps (some of those diagnostics installed with the full media that I mentioned) [which are described here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10640_.htm) and which can help determine if a problem is with the installation or with the code.

Comment: The scenario is i am using a java program to access a MQ queue deployed on a separate machine via JMS,so i got all the required MQ client libs from the server, the weirdness lies in the fact that the same program runs perfectly on the server where MQ is deployed with the same jars in classpath, may be it has something to do with java.library.path prop, any more ideas. :)

Comment: The error message clearly says that java.library.path is missing mqjbnd.  If you go to the server on which it works, I'm sure you'll find that its java.library.path is set properly.  Make yours the same and it'll work, I'm sure.

Comment: This is the reason that IBM does not support this type of install. If you use the MQC7 SupportPac to install the client then you get *all* the required libs and jars as well as diagnostic utilities. According to your comment, the one place where the install media was used, it works. Why not use the documented and supported procedure to install the client libs? Then you could open PMRs if needed and apply maintenance.  Or are these things not important for your application?

Comment: it works when the client and server reside in the same machine, but not in separate..

Comment: Or from  my perspective, it works on the machine where IBM's install media was run and not on the machine where the jars were installed by copying them over.  As an IBM consultant specializing in WMQ I see this a lot.  The first thing I get my clients to do is run the supported install as per the documentation.  This fixes 80% ~ 90% of the problems such as you are reporting.  If you are unwilling to run the install media on the client machine, I can't help you further.  If it still doesn't work with the full install, I'd ask to see the output of the Initial Verification Test program run.

Comment: I have installed it using the process mentioned in the IBM manual Chapter 3 "Installing a Websphere MQ Client", on Linux 64 bit.
Following command  gives me this result.
dspmqver -p 63
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.6
CMVC level:  p701-106-110725
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
.
.
.
Name:        IBM WebSphere MQ
Version:     7.0.1.6
CMVC Level:  k701-106-110721 mqjbnd=CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found. [3=mqjbnd]::no mqjbnd in java.library.path
Build Type:  Production

DistHub Build Level: DH610-GOLD
Webscale Distribution Hub Core

Comment: @T.Rob hi, can you please fix the link for "There are a few Install Verification Test apps ..."? Thanks ;-)

Comment: @Betlista perhaps the server was down? The link works for me now.  However it is for v7.0 and so here's a current one: [Post installation setup for WebSphere MQ classes for JMS applications - v7.5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031700_.htm)

Comment: Thanks, new links works fine, while the previous one still not working (empty page shows here in Europe), 7.5 is better anyway ;-)

I found this one (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508) really helpful, but its not working anyway :-( All properties are configured, but `dspmqver.exe` shows "The native JNI library '?' was not found." I didn't find good step by step tutorial how to make samples working...

Comment: You may need to clear cookies.  The Infocenter shows up blank for me a lot too, but when I clear cookies (and sometimes cache) it comes right back.  Note that the Infocenters are served from different IBM sites beginning with v7.5 so it behaves differently. At the moment I have access to all four Infocenters from v6.0 to v7.5. Latest Firefox, Win 7x64, NoScript, USA IP addy.

Comment: Did you do [setmqinst](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15635_.htm) after install?

Comment: @T.Rob after running setmqinst it told me to restart PC, what I didn't before probably, now the dspmqver.exe works. I also found that those links I refered to as not working does not work in Chrome, but they work fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 9):

Probably a bit late but I had the same problem and found that this can be avoided if you use a different Connection Mode when connecting to a remote Queue. By default the `MQConnectionFactory` uses `WMQ_CM_BINDINGS` as it's connection mode. If you change it to `WMQ_CM_CLIENT` (or whichever connection mode you like that doesn't require native libraries) you should be fine.

```
@Test
public void testMQConnectionMode() throws JMSException {
    MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
    assertThat(cf.getIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE), is(equalTo(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS)));
    cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    assertThat(cf.getIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE), is(equalTo(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)));
}
```

Comment: As someone also struggling with this problem, I'd like to clarify that switching to WMQ_CM_CLIENT is necessary but not sufficient. I also needed to include "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar" in my set of library jars. Just for info, this in turn pulls in jms.jar, com.ibm.mq.headers.jar and com.ibm.mq.jar . I'm still seeing (other) problems, though, so more jars may be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Johnam, it happened because the ConnectionFactory set as server by default, it need to be set as client, you said that it works on same machine. Because I also met the same situation, it run when on same machine, in this case because your machine is as WMQ Server so do the program, but when you run on different machine then your program must set as client.

I fix it using set some parameter on ConnectionFactory:

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
....
<property name="transportType" value="1" />
<property name="clientReconnectTimeout" value="2" /> 
<property name="clientReconnectOptions" value="0" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The VM parameter `-Djava.library.path=/opt/mqm/java/lib64` works for me. My environment is 64bit Suse with MQ installed and my program is using 'Bindings' transport type

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Path variable on system properties. Try to run code by specifying MQInstallation Dir :\Lib64 path before MQInstallation Dir :\Lib

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your tomcat arguments:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64"
```

If the installation directory is different than the above, use the appropriate location.