# com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have created a Spring Boot application with JMS .I am using IBM MQ7 and trying to make a connection through client to access a queue with Spring JMS. Could anyone please help I am a newbie.

I am getting error in eclipse

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue1' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd' was not found.
```

However I have tried to setup java.library.path in JVM arguments & Eclipse.ini in eclipse but still getting same error.

```
In Run Configuration: VM Arguments
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib64\mqjbnd.dll"
```

I have followed
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675883/accessing-mq-with-jms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031570_.htm)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031570_.htm

I still getting same exception.

JMS Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses =
{
    MessageListener.class
})
public class JmsConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsConfig.class);


    @Value("${ibm.mq.hostname}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.port}")
    private Integer port;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.manager}")
    private String queueManager;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.channel}")
    private String channel;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.queue}")
    private String queue;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.timeout}")
    private long timeout;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Resource
    private MessageListener listener;
    @Bean
    public MQTopicConnectionFactory mqTopicConnectionFactory() {
        MQTopicConnectionFactory mqTopicConnectionFactory = new MQTopicConnectionFactory();
        try {   
            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);

            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqTopicConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error connecting to MQ: {}",e.getMessage());
        }
        return mqTopicConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter(MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername(username);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword(password);
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        try {   
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);                    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error connecting to MQ: {}",e.getMessage());
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }


     @Bean
        public DefaultMessageListenerContainer myAppListenerContainer()
        {
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
            listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
            listenerContainer.setDestinationName(queue);
            listenerContainer.setMessageListener(listener);
            //listenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumers);
            listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
            return listenerContainer;
        }

     @Bean
     @Primary
     public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter) {
         CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
         cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter);
         cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(500);
         cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
         return cachingConnectionFactory;
     }
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate queueTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(timeout);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the queue manager run on the same server as the spring boot application? What specific version of MQ jar file(s) are you running?

Comment: `mqjbnd` is only required to connect in server binding mode to a queue manager running local on the same server.

Comment: @JoshMc I have set up local environment for Ibm Mq but queueManager , queue are on the remote server & client is also on local machine. I have attached the Jars for reference.

Comment: 7.0 has been out of support since September 2015, 7.0.1.3 was released in August 2010.  I would suggest you start by downloading 9.1.0.5 all client package and stop using an almost 10 year old software release that had been unsupported for almost 5 years when you are writing new software.

Comment: New IBM MQ classes for JMS versions product better errors as well that will likely help track down the problem you are having.  As I mentioned above you don't need to worry about libpath or the `mqjbnd` error, this is normal and is how the MQ JMS client checks to see if the mq server software is installed on the same server as the client, in your case this is not true so there is no need to worry about this as it is not a real error.

Comment: The fact that it seems to be looking for this library might be related to it not getting the channel name/hostname/port/etc that you are passing into the `MQQueueConnectionFactory()`.

Comment: Also even by standards of 7.0.1.x version you are at 7.0.1.3, the last release of 7.0.1.x was 7.0.1.14 in August 2016, this contained almost 6 years of defect fixes, but as I mentioned this version is not supported.  The next version was 7.1 which came out in Nov 2011 and went out of support in April 2017, 7.5 came out in July 2012 and went out of support April 2018, 8.0 came out June 2014 and GOES out of support in 2 days (April 2020), 9.0 came out June 2016 and will go out of support Sep 2021, 9.1 came out July 2018 and will be supported at least to July 2023.

Comment: See this link for a tutorial,  [Download, install and test IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All (com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-install-and-test-ibm-mq-install-java-all-comibmmqallclientjar).

Answer (score 4):

> The files are missing because they are not provided nor needed in a client install since you would not be connecting via bindings mode on a client only install. ([source](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-mq-client-installation-missing-mqjbdll-files))

Somehow default (WMQ_CM_BINDINGS = 0) transport type for `ConnectionFactory` get used for `ConnectionFactory` which fails.

This doesn't work

```
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

This works

```
mqQueueConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
```

Other properties works as expected. Here is factory declaration

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ibm.mq")
public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    factory.setIntProperty(WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    return factory;
}
```

with config

```
ibm.mq:
  queueManager: <manager>
  channel: <channel>
  hostName: <host>
  port: <port>
  user: <user>
  password: <pass>
```